# Shared Elements is not working as it should (strange behavior)

Tags: android, kotlin, transition

Apparently I'm doing all the steps correctly, but the transition isn't working properly.

I opened a new very simple project, with only two activities, in the MainActivity layout I have an ImageView centered and in SecondActivity I have the same ImageView, but bigger

The following happens:

When I open the application and click on the image, it opens the SecondActivity but no transition, now still in SecondActivity, when I press the back button, it goes back to MainActivity, but still without transition. And from now on, when I click on ImageView, SecondActivity doesn't open anymore, however, when I minimize the application (when going through onPause) and come back, SecondActivity is open, and when I press the back button, the "reverse transition " occurs correctly.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu_image_view"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/cardapio"
        android:transitionName="image"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val menuImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.menu_image_view)
        menuImageView.transitionName = "image"

        val i = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)

        val options: Bundle? = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
            this, menuImageView, "image"
        ).toBundle()

        menuImageView.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(i, options)
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="600dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/cardapio"
        android:transitionName="image"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**SecondActivity.kt**

```
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        // To support reverse transitions when user clicks the device back button
        supportFinishAfterTransition()
    }
}
```

And my **themes.xml**:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.Animations" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I've already tried using both the
**`<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>`**
and the
**`<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>`**

Could it be an Android Studio bug?

Comment: Have you tried to put `i` and `options` inside `setOnClickListener` ?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I'm feeling completely silly right now ahaha! It worked, could you explain to me why? I'm curious now

Comment: You may check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to them inside `onClickListener` . If you put inside `onCreate`, it will create it once the activity is created. When you minimized the apps, only `onPaused` will be triggered.

```
    menuImageView.setOnClickListener {
        val i = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)

        val options: Bundle? = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(
        this, menuImageView, "image"
        ).toBundle()
        startActivity(i, options)
    }
```